# Get byte array file from Restful web service to android

Tags: android, file, rest, arrays, firebird

I am new here and I want first to ask excuses if I don't get to express very well myself or for my English!!

In fact, I'm working on a project that is supposed to get byte array from a Firebird database and represent them on android.
So I decided to use a **restful webservice with a methode** that get these daten from database and then use android client to retrieve them.

How can I please write these bytes in a text file and then get this using an android client!

The methode on web service looks like this:

```
 @GET
    @Path("daten/{id}")
    @Produces("text/plain")
  *// Instead of byte[] I wanted to return a file because this doesn't work*
    public byte[] getDaten(@PathParam("id") String id){
      Tbpatereignis res= (Tbpatereignis) em.createQuery("select erg from Tbpatereignis as erg where erg.vcereignis= :ekgtyp and erg.vcpatsur.vcsurrogat= :id ").setParameter("ekgtyp", "UREKG").setParameter("id", id).getResultList().get(0);

      return res.getBldivers();
    }
```

How can I then retreive this file from a restful web service and use it later on android?

Thanks for ur help!

Answer (score 1):

you should use @Produces("application/octet-stream") not @Produces("text/plain").
In android client you can use httpclient or URLConnection to issue http request.

example code for URLConnection to get image from server:

```
URL url = new URL(urlStr);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(connection.getInputStream());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the byte array directly form your database, using MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM.

On the server (endpoint) side:

```
@GET
  @Path("fetch-image")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
  public Response getImageArray(
    @HeaderParam(IMAGE_ID) String image_id) {

    // return image requested as byte array
    return Response.ok(MyDBFunctions.fetchImage(image_id), MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
  }
```

On Android (consumer) side:

```
public <T> T getImage(Class<T> responseType, String image_id) throws ClientErrorException {
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient());
        WebTarget webTarget = client.target(BASE_URI).path("fetch-image");

        // return image as byte array
        return webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                .header(IMAGE_ID, image_id)
                .get(responseType);
    }
```

And finally, to load an image:

```
Response resp = data.getImage(Response.class, image_id);
                if (resp.getStatus() == HTTP_STATUS_OK) {
                    // load image from server
                    image = resp.readEntity(byte[].class);
                }
                resp.close();
```